# Sound emulation in splash

Tags: scrapy, splash-screen

I try open video in youtube via Splash, and i see some problems.

> ALSA lib confmisc.c:768:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
>
> ALSA lib conf.c:4248:(_snd_config_evaluate) function
>   snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
>
> ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
>
> ALSA lib conf.c:4248:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat
>   returned error: No such file or directory
>
> ALSA lib confmisc.c:1251:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
>
> ALSA lib conf.c:4248:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer
>   returned error: No such file or directory
>
> ALSA lib conf.c:4727:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file
>   or directory
>
> ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
>
> ALSA lib pcm_hw.c:1667:(_snd_pcm_hw_open) Invalid value for card

What's package should i add in docker for run it?

Comment: This has been answered in some [archlinux forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=94696).

Comment: But how i can do it inside docker?

Comment: Possibly if it's a ubuntu image, you can run `sudo apt-get alsa-utils` as one of the commands.